# php difference between 1 and '1'

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have struggle with this problem for hours. I have this method my model (codeigniter) :

```
public function get_umat($kelas1 = 0, $kelas2 = 0) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('msumat');
    $this->db->join('mskelas', 'msumat.kelas_id = mskelas.kelas_id');

    if($kelas1 != 0)
    {
        echo $kelas1;
        var_dump($kelas1);
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas1);
    }
    else if($kelas2 !=0)
    {
        echo '2';
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas2);
    }
    else if($kelas1 != 0 && $kelas2 !=0)
    {
        echo '3';
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id BETWEEN $kelas1 AND $kelas2');
    }

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

**EDIT :**
The one that **not** working is in this line of code (taken from above) :

```
$this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas1);
```

Its **not** working when i called this method in my controller, like this :

```
$this->backend_m->get_umat($_POST['ddl_kelas1'], $_POST['ddl_kelas1']);
```

I get '1'(**String**) when i vardump the `($_POST['ddl_kelas1']`

Then i try to **change the parameter in the controller**, but its still **not** working :

```
 $this->backend_m->get_umat(1, $_POST['ddl_kelas1']);
```

Desperately, **i tried to change the parameter directly in the model, and its working** :

```
public function get_umat($kelas1 = 1, $kelas2 = 0)
```

Whats going on here?i think it has something to do with the difference of 1 (int) and '1' (String). Thanks :D

Edit 2 :
After some experiment, i think variable type is not the problem here. Thats because :
I tried to do this in my **controller** :

```
        if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])) 
    {
        $test = (int)$_POST['ddl_kelas1'];
        $this->backend_m->get_umat($_POST['ddl_kelas1'] , $_POST['ddl_kelas1']);
    }
```

And this in my model :

```
if((int)$kelas1 != 0)
    {
        echo $kelas1;
        var_dump($kelas1);
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas1);
    }
```

What i get is, the `$kelas1` is already an int now, but the code is still **not** working. I think it has something to do with `$_POST` in my `select` in html, or something else :D

However, this code is still working perfectly (just like above, i manually changed the parameter to 1 (integer)) :

```
public function get_umat($kelas1 = 1, $kelas2 = 0)
```

This is my full controller code :

```
public function index() {
    //table     
    $data_umat = $this->backend_m->get_umat()->result();

    $this->table->set_heading(
        'No',
        'Nama',
        'Kelas',
        'Alamat',
        'Sekolah',
        'Nomor Telepon',
        'Keterangan'        
    );

    $table_template = array('table_open' => '<table border="1" id="custom_table">');
    $this->table->set_template($table_template);

    $no = 1;
    foreach($data_umat as $list_temp) 
    {
        $this->table->add_row(
            $no++,
            $list_temp->nama,
            $list_temp->kelas,
            $list_temp->alamat,
            $list_temp->sekolah,
            $list_temp->no_tlpn,
            $list_temp->keterangan
        );
    }

    $data_kelas = $this->backend_m->get_kelas()->result();

    $data['list_kelas'][0] = 'Pilih Kelas';

    foreach($data_kelas as $row)
    {
        $data['list_kelas'][$row->kelas_id] = $row->kelas;
    }

    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

    $this->load->view('backend/home_v', $data);


        if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])) 
    {
        //$test = (int)$_POST['ddl_kelas1'];
        $test = (int)$this->input->post('ddl_kelas1');
        $this->backend_m->get_umat($test , $_POST['ddl_kelas1'], $_POST['txtNama']);
    }

}
```

Pretty confusing, meh?

**EASY ANSWER FOR THOSE WHO HAVE THE SAME PROBLEM**
Use `$_POST` or `$this->input->post()` in model, **not** in controller. So we **dont** have to call the model's method.

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Describe what *is* happening and what you expect.

Comment: 1 could de an integer, '1' is a varchar

Comment: It could be worth doing a `var_dump` of the parameters coming into your `get_umat` method to see what is being passed in. With the where statement, if I recall correctly, the string value is escaped where as a integer value is not. I'm not sure if MySQL can do type juggling like PHP can.

Comment: @Gavin yes, the sql needs int while my variable always string...i have tried to cast it(like in the answers) but not working :D

Comment: As an aside, in the future, since you are using CI, you can use the `input` class to get your POST variables, for example, `$this->input->post('some_data');`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information @MarcAudet :D I have tried that, but its not solving this problem :D

Comment: You have tried many things.  Can you update your post and show the latest `get_umat` code AND the controller code where you are testing it.  Also, see my answer with strategies.  Echo out the SQL statements so we can identify the problem.  Right now we are guessing.

Comment: So at the moment, when you render your page at `$this->load->view('backend/home_v', $data);` you have selected all your records from your table and the output is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the expressions in your if statements:

```
if((int)$kelas1 != 0)
{...}
else if((int)$kelas2 !=0)
{...}
else if((int)$kelas1 != 0 && (int)$kelas2 !=0)
{...}
```

Add the `(int)` to make sure you compare integers to integers (or strings to strings).  The same idea applies in building your SQL statements.

**Debugging Strategies**
Try one or more of the following ideas:

(1) Make sure that integers are being passed into your `get_mat` function:

```
public function get_umat((int)$kelas1 = 0, (int)$kelas2 = 0) {...)
```

(2) Make sure that `get_umat` works when passing in hard-coded values:

```
get_umat(0,0);
get_umat(1,0);
get_umat(0,1);
get_umat(1,1);
```

In each case, check to make sure the right `WHERE` clause is selected.

ALSO: echo out your SQL statement and double check it for syntax.  Try something like:

```
$the_sql_query_string = $this->db->last_query();
```

and echo/look at `$the_sql_query_string`

**--------------- Code Suggestions --------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I made some suggestions to the code.  Put in some real values for `$kelas1` and `$kelas2` and make sure your output looks correct.

```
public function index() {
    // Select all or filtered set of records     
    if(isset($this->input->post('btnSearch')) 
    {
        //$test = (int)$_POST['ddl_kelas1'];
        //$test = (int)$this->input->post('ddl_kelas1');

        $kelas1 = 101; // put in a relevant id
        $kelas2 = 201; // put in a second relevant id

        // In term, try the following: 
        $this->backend_m->get_umat($kelas1,$kelas2);
    }

    $data_umat = $this->backend_m->get_umat()->result();

    $this->table->set_heading(
        'No',
        'Nama',
        'Kelas',
        'Alamat',
        'Sekolah',
        'Nomor Telepon',
        'Keterangan'        
    );

    $table_template = array('table_open' => '<table border="1" id="custom_table">');
    $this->table->set_template($table_template);

    $no = 1;
    foreach($data_umat as $list_temp) 
    {
        $this->table->add_row(
            $no++,
            $list_temp->nama,
            $list_temp->kelas,
            $list_temp->alamat,
            $list_temp->sekolah,
            $list_temp->no_tlpn,
            $list_temp->keterangan
        );
    }

    $data_kelas = $this->backend_m->get_kelas()->result();

    $data['list_kelas'][0] = 'Pilih Kelas';

    foreach($data_kelas as $row)
    {
        $data['list_kelas'][$row->kelas_id] = $row->kelas;
    }

    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate();

    $this->load->view('backend/home_v', $data);


    // This will not do anything since you have already rendered the page
    // This should be at the top of the code
    /*
    if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])) 
    {
        //$test = (int)$_POST['ddl_kelas1'];
        $test = (int)$this->input->post('ddl_kelas1');
        $this->backend_m->get_umat($test , $_POST['ddl_kelas1'], $_POST['txtNama']);
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :D, its still not working.  The sql needs int while my variable always string...i have tried to cast it but not working :D

Comment: Thanks for your help :D Well, your answer is not solving my problem, but after i debug it, i realized that we CANT $_POST in controller (i dont know why), so i change the $_POST position in my model :D Maybe you can help me again?

Comment: Were you trying to update the $_POST array values?  You need to post your controller code so that we can see how you are callings things.

Comment: Okay, i will post it in the question :D

Answer (score 1):

Cast your variables as integer.

```
$this->backend_m->get_umat((int)$_POST['ddl_kelas1'], (int)$_POST['ddl_kelas1']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its not wprking. Please see my edited question. Thanks :D

Comment: @BlazeTama, What does `var_dump($kelas1);` give you?

Comment: @Starx string(1) "1".  The sql needs int while my variable always string...i have tried to cast it but not working :D

Answer (score 1):

You will select data that matches a key with a string, try to cast the value to get correct data :

```
public function get_umat($kelas1 = 0, $kelas2 = 0) {
    $kelas1 = (int)$kelas1;
    $kelas2 = (int)$kelas2;
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('msumat');
    $this->db->join('mskelas', 'msumat.kelas_id = mskelas.kelas_id');

    if($kelas1 != 0)
    {
        echo $kelas1;
        var_dump($kelas1);
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas1);
    }
    else if($kelas2 !=0)
    {
        echo '2';
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id', $kelas2);
    }
    else if($kelas1 != 0 && $kelas2 !=0)
    {
        echo '3';
        $this->db->where('mskelas.kelas_id BETWEEN $kelas1 AND $kelas2');
    }

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but its not wprking. Please see my edited question. Thanks :D